Removing non-brain part (eyeball) in DWI/DW-MRI brain mask using MRtrix3’s dwi2mask command
For one of my subjects, when I use dwi2mask from MRtrix3, the mask includes one eyeball. How can I remove the eye? Thank you!
I tried rerunning it and looking for extra flags to include.
I am wondering if there is an option for dwi2mask's command that can be used?
